# BindingSource does't work on label MONO c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, mono, bindingsource

I has the followinng code to make update of more control refers to the same variable on windows form.

I make it to update more than one control by asingle operation on update datatable.

This working very well on Window, calling UpdateControlValue by  BeginInvoke.Action from main form. When I execute this code by mono on linux on raspian, it does't work.
Thank's for help

````
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable tabella1 = new DataTable(TABLE_NAME);
private const string TABLE_NAME = "CostantTable";
private const string COLUMN_NAME = "CtrlName";
private const string COLUMN_VALUE = "CtrlValue";
     
     public HmiMappingManager()
     {            
         tabella1.Columns.Add(COLUMN_NAME, typeof(string));
         tabella1.Columns.Add(COLUMN_VALUE, typeof(string));
         
         var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ControlMapEnum));

         foreach (var val in values)
         {
             string defaultValue = DecorationHelper.GetDescription((ControlMapEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ControlMapEnum), val.ToString()));
             tabella1.Rows.Add(new object[2] { val.ToString(), defaultValue });
         }

         ds.Tables.Add(tabella1);
         ds.AcceptChanges();
     }
           
     public void AssignConstantToControl(List<System.Windows.Forms.Control> controlToAssociate, ControlMapEnum controlId)
     {           
         BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
         bs1.DataSource = ds;
         bs1.DataMember = TABLE_NAME;
         bs1.Filter = COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + controlId.ToString() + "'";

         foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control control in controlToAssociate)
             control.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs1, COLUMN_VALUE);

     }
     
   
     public void UpdateControlValue(ControlMapEnum controlId, string newValue)
     {            
             DataRow dr = tabella1.Select(COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + controlId.ToString() + "'").FirstOrDefault();

             if (dr == null)
                 return;

             int index = tabella1.Rows.IndexOf(dr);

             tabella1.Rows[index].BeginEdit();
             tabella1.Rows[index][COLUMN_VALUE] = newValue;
             tabella1.Rows[index].EndEdit();               
             LoggerManagerUtility.Instance.Log(LogLevel.Info, this, "END UPDATE CONTROL" + controlId + " TEXT TO VISUALIZE: " + newValue);

         
     }
      

 ```
````

Comment: WinForms works "very well on Windows", because it is only supported by Microsoft on Windows. Mono is going away, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ so your only choice is to migrate to another UI framework to go cross platform, https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: How dou you suggets? Uno platform is not to ok other? .netcore need of mono...